# Retrieving QPushButton from QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I have a QPushButton with related icon, and I add it to a scene:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
button->setIcon(QIcon(myIcon));
buttonWidget = detail->scene()->addWidget(button);
// buttonWidget is declared globally and is a QGraphicsProxyWidget*
```

Later on, in a different function, the `buttonWidget` is still accessible. How can I retrieve the `QPushButton` object from the `buttonWidget`? I would like to change its icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`QGraphicsProxyWidget::widget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#widget) to get the underlying `QWidget*` and then use `dynamic_cast` to cast to `QPushButton*`:

```
QPushbutton *otherButton = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(buttonWidget->widget());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the object as a QWidget using `QGraphicsProxyWidget::widget` and then casting to a `QPushButton`.

But I'd recommand to make the `QPushButton` be an attribute of your class (always better that casting). Then you access it later whenevr you want.

```
button = new QPushButton; // declare button as an attribute of your class in the header file
button->setIcon(QIcon(myIcon));
buttonWidget=detail->scene()->addWidget(button);
```